# IsAuthorizeEndpoint is always false even for api protected with [Authorize] attribute in OWIN setup

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin, jwt

When I overrode "MatchEndpoint", all I find is that a call to a method that was decorated with [Authorize] showed up with "IsAuthorizeEndpoint" and "IsTokenEndpoint" both set to false. The latter makes sense to me, the former does not.

As a result I keep getting "Authorization has been denied for this request." message. The token endpoint works correctly I can retrieve the token which I pass as bearer in the authorization header in the call to protected Api.

I am using OWIN middle ware in an asp.net webapi 2.0 with JWT mechanism

Can you guys point out what can be the possible reasons for this ?